# controller extension not found

Tags: controller, error, controller-extension

I created a controller extension for the Contact object. I don't know if it will work or not, because I can not test it. Salesforce is acting like my controller extension does not exist.

```
Error: Unknown method 'ContactStandardController.task()'
```

To figure out what was going on, I copypasted the controller and vf page and tried to used it for a separate custom object. The vf page saved normally and gave me no error.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a snippet of the vf page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" extensions="ContactExtensionController">

<!-- Define Tab panel .css styles -->
<style>
.activeTab {background-color: #081f3f; color:white; background-image:none}
.inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black; background-image:none}
</style>

<a href="/003/o"> &#60;&#60; Back to List</a><br/><br/>

<!-- Create Tab panel -->   
<apex:tabPanel switchType="server" selectedTab="Contact" id="ContacttabPanel"
tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" styleClass="openInPopup">
<apex:tab label="Contact Information" name="name" id="Contact">
<apex:form > 

<apex:pageBlock >        
<apex:pageBlockSection >          
<apex:outputText style="font-size:20px;text-align:left;color:{!IF(Contact.Sales_Status__c = 'Proposal'||Contact.Sales_Status__c='Listing'||Contact.Sales_Status__c='Escrow'||Contact.Sales_Status__c='Sales Comp', 'red', '#081f3f')};" value="{0} | {1}"> 
<apex:param value="{!Contact.Name}"/>
<apex:param value="{!Contact.Sales_Status__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
</apex:pageblocksection>

<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!task}" value="Log A Call"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Here's the controller extension:

```
public class ContactExtensionController{
    Contact Contact;

    public ContactExtensionController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        Contact = (Contact)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference save()
    {
        update Contact;
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference task()
    {
            String sServerName = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
        sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
        String taskURL='00T/e?who_id='+Contact.id+'&followup=1&tsk5=Call&retURL=%2F'+Contact.id;
        PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName + taskURL); 
        retPage.setRedirect(true);
        return null;
        }



}
```

I'm sure I will get lots of comments about how my method is bad and doesn't work. But I can't change it to something that does work until I can actually *use* my extension. So I would like to figure out why that is.

Comment: Can you try to change the method's name `task()` and then try to save.

Comment: I just tried changing it to "logCall"...same result unfortunately

Comment: Also tried signing out of salesforce and closing everything and resigning in

Comment: Try renaming the Contact object from "Contact" to something else.

Comment: Do you have by any chance a class called `ContactStandardController` ?

Comment: No,,,,I do not.

Comment: Can you try to update the `Contact` to `Public final Contact myContact {get;set;}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37730/discussion-between-raym0nd-and-mrg).

Comment: UPDATE:
I tried using system.debug() in the controller, and in the debug log I do not see any user_debug lines.  

So, I now believe that the contactrextensioncontroller maybe is not being passed to the vf page at all. Why would this be?

Comment: Can you post the full code here? I think it's something that's not included that's at fault — I just saved your code (completing the tabs etc.) and didn't get an error using the exact same extension controller.

Comment: I made a copy of the controllerextension that is exactly the same, and a version of the vf page that is shortened but otherwise exactly the same. Still giving me the same error. I'll paste them to pastebin

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aZcgai2m

Comment: there's some javascript at the top of this that I left out of the version I posted earlier. I don't think this should've been an issue, and If you comment out everything between the <script> tags it will behave exactly the same. But yes, I realize this part is different.

Comment: I just saved the page you put in paste bin (replacing `Sales_Status__c` with `Email`) and didn't get the error when viewing the page, with or without a contact Id... this is getting to be quite intriguing. Don't suppose it's a dev org you can share access to?

Comment: The error is now going away with the copy (controller2) but not with the original So I guess I will just use the copy

Answer (score 0):

The entire controller extension was not passing to the vf page. Not sure why. I made an exact copy of the vf page and the controller and everything worked normally and the error went away.

So I guess this was just some weird fluke. Thanks guys for trying to help!

Answer (score -1):

Declare contact as, `private final Contact Contact;` Can you try changing constructor as following, `this.objHoliday = (Holiday__c)controller.getrecord();`

Comment: I tried this as well

Comment: By default classes are with sharing...

Comment: I edited my answer, can you try that.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested...am still getting the same error